# Change the melody of human speech using FFT and polynomial interpolation

Tags: python, stft

**I'm trying to do the following:**

1. Extract the melody of me asking a question (word "**Hey?**" recorded to
   wav) so I get a melody pattern that I can apply to any other
   recorded/synthesized speech (basically how F0 changes in time).
2. Use polynomial interpolation (Lagrange?) so I get a function that describes the melody (approximately of course).
3. Apply the function to another recorded voice sample. (eg. word "**Hey.**" so it's transformed to a question "**Hey?**", or transform the end of a sentence to sound like a question [eg. "**Is it ok.**" => "**Is it ok?**"]). Voila, that's it.

**What I have done? Where am I?**
Firstly, I have dived into the math that stands behind the fft and signal processing (basics). I want to do it programatically so I decided to use python.

I performed the fft on the entire "**Hey?**" voice sample and got data in frequency domain (please don't mind y-axis units, I haven't normalized them)
[image: ffted sample one]

So far so good. Then I decided to divide my signal into chunks so I get more clear frequency information - peaks and so on - this is a blind shot, me trying to grasp the idea of manipulating the frequency and analyzing the audio data. It gets me nowhere however, not in a direction I want, at least.

[image: ffted sample two]

Now, if I took those peaks, got an interpolated function from them, and applied the function on another voice sample (a part of a voice sample, that is also ffted of course) and performed inversed fft I **wouldn't get** what I wanted, right?
I would only change the magnitude so it wouldn't affect the melody itself (I think so).

Then I used **[spec](https://librosa.org/doc/latest/generated/librosa.display.specshow.html)** and **[pyin](https://librosa.org/doc/latest/generated/librosa.pyin.html)** methods from **librosa** to extract the real F0-in-time - the melody of asking question "**Hey?**". And as we would expect, we can clearly see an increase in frequency value:
[image: ffted spectrogram and the course of f0 in time "Hey?"]

And a non-question statement looks like this - let's say it's moreless constant.
[image: spectrogram non-question]

The same applies to a longer speech sample:
[image: monotonous speech sample]

Now, I assume that I have blocks to build my algorithm/process but I still don't know how to assemble them beacause there are some blanks in my understanding of what's going on under the hood.

I consider that I need to find a way to map the F0-in-time curve from the spectrogram to the "pure" FFT data, get an interpolated function from it and then apply the function on another voice sample (I mean curve fitting)

**Is there any elegant (inelegant would be ok too) way to do this? I need to be pointed in a right direction because I can feel I'm close but I'm basically stuck.
I need to increase/manipulate frequencies at certain point in time, I know it does mean to move data from one bin to another but I need to know how to work with the STFT data.

**

The code that works behind the above charts is taken just from the librosa docs and other stackoverflow questions, it's just a draft/POC so please don't comment on style, if you could :)

fft in chunks:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.io import wavfile
import os

file = os.path.join("dir", "hej_n_nat.wav")
fs, signal = wavfile.read(file)

CHUNK = 1024

afft = np.abs(np.fft.fft(signal[0:CHUNK]))
freqs = np.linspace(0, fs, CHUNK)[0:int(fs / 2)]
spectrogram_chunk = freqs / np.amax(freqs * 1.0)

# Plot spectral analysis
plt.plot(freqs[0:250], afft[0:250])
plt.show()
```

spectrogram:

```
import librosa.display
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

file = os.path.join("/path/to/dir", "hej_n_nat.wav")
y, sr = librosa.load(file, sr=44100)
f0, voiced_flag, voiced_probs = librosa.pyin(y, fmin=librosa.note_to_hz('C2'), fmax=librosa.note_to_hz('C7'))


times = librosa.times_like(f0)

D = librosa.amplitude_to_db(np.abs(librosa.stft(y)), ref=np.max)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

img = librosa.display.specshow(D, x_axis='time', y_axis='log', ax=ax)

ax.set(title='pYIN fundamental frequency estimation')

fig.colorbar(img, ax=ax, format="%+2.f dB")

ax.plot(times, f0, label='f0', color='cyan', linewidth=2)

ax.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

Hints, questions and comments much appreciated.

Comment: very interesting, but what I would do to apply an intonation change is to try to work exactly as the auto-tune works .. first extract the pitch contour from the word "OK" then extract the Pitch contour from the word "OK?" now compare the pitch differences between the two and apply those differences to each chunk with a pitch shift, you might also need a little bit of time scale change

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's already answered on SO itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've answered the same question on stackoverflow. I've managed to modify F0 by modyfying stft output and the compute it back to amplitudes.

Answer is here, I won't be duplicating the same text here on DSP.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63339608/change-the-melody-of-human-speech-using-fft-and-polynomial-interpolation

Answer (score 0):

The low quefrency MFCC coefficients might be a place to start.

I read a few articles by Stylianou from a few years back where he did funky stuff to peoples voice (gender and age modification).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The thing is that I know what properties of a sound sample have to be transformed in order to achieve my goal. I need to modify f0 -the fundamental frequency which I have extracted and shown above (blue line on the spectrogram - how f0 changes in time - the melody). for instance I can increase frequency in a program like Audacity - I just modify spectrogram, the frequency goes up and speech sounds "higher". Here I need to do the same thing, modify f0 and its harmonics, but I'm not sure how to do it correctly, there are libs for pitch shifting but not in a way I need.